# Display an Apex Chart in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, datatable, apexcharts

I'm struggling to add a chart in a datatable. I'm using Apex chart and DataTable jquery plugins.

I'm getting the following message "Error: Element not found apexcharts.min.js:14".
I suppose is due to id="apex-mixed-2 is not yet available when Apex renders the chart but I cannot find a solution.

By the moment I would like to add the same chart for all the data rows.

**Datatable Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#products-datatable").DataTable({
        ajax:{url: "../assets/data/jsdata.json",dataSrc:""},
        columns: [
            {
                "data": "Url",
                "render": function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<img src="'+data+'" alt="table-user" class="mr-2 rounded-circle" style="height: 70px;"/>';
                }
            },       
            { "data": "Customer" },
            { "data": "Phone" },
            { "data": "Balance" },
            { "data": "Orders" },
            { "data": "Last Order" },
            { "data": "Status" }
            {
                "data": "Graph",
                "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return ' <div id="apex-mixed-2"</div>';
                }
            }            
        ]
    })
});
```

**A simple Apex chart**

```
   var options = {
      series: [{
        name: "Desktops",
        data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148]
    }],
      chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'line',
      zoom: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'straight'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Product Trends by Month',
      align: 'left'
    },
    grid: {
      row: {
        colors: ['#f3f3f3', 'transparent'], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
        opacity: 0.5
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep'],
    }
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#apex-mixed-2"), options);
    chart.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute code after the AJAX request made by Datatables to load the content has completed use the `drawCallback` property.

```js
$('#products-datatable').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '../assets/data/jsdata.json',
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  drawCallback: () => {
    // call your chart initialisation code here...
  }, 
  columns: [
    {
      data: 'Url',
      render: data => `<img src='${data}' alt='table-user' class='mr-2 rounded-circle' style='height: 70px;'/>`
    },       
    { data: 'Customer' },
    { data: 'Phone' },
    { data: 'Balance' },
    { data: 'Orders' },
    { data: 'Last Order' },
    { data: 'Status' }
    {
      data: 'Graph',
      render: () => ' <div id="apex-mixed-2"></div>'
    }            
  ]
})
```

Comment: It wouldn't work I'm adding the <div id='apex-mixed-2'</div>' on Datatable creation if I call the chart initialisation on drawCallback the div id will not be available yet. I'm trying to find if it is posible get the html from chart render and return it on a function.

Comment: Apologies - there was a couple of mistakes in that part. I've updated the question to fix them. Also, if you have JS code which doesn't behave as you expect, open the console in devtools to find the error causing the issue